# how to convert $1.91$ (CAD)/kg into dollars/lbs?

Tags: ratio

edit: how to convert $1.91$(CAD)/kg into dollar/lbs?

I was looking at some grocery pricing and I couldn't figure how to convert back into lbs as some stores will list it in lbs, and others will list it in kg.

How to convert $1.91$(CAD)/kg into dollars/lbs?

Comment: What is denoted  (CAD)?

Comment: Write a letter to congress and implore them to join the metric system.

Comment: is think CAD means Canadian dollar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $1$ lb. = $0.45359237$ kg, $1$ kg is $2.20462262$ lbs. So, $$\frac{1.91}{2.20462262} \approx 0.87$$ canadian dollar/pound. One canadian dollar is worth $0.8$ dollar (as of February 16), so the result is approximately $0.7$ dollar/lb.